# Sequence of identical characters in Ncurses not displaying properly

Tags: ncurses, xterm

New to NCurses, here.

I'm having a weird problem when trying to show an array that contains a sequence of identical characters (more than 6 in sequence), where the window only shows a single character from the sequence.

It happens with something as simple as:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    char test[] = "AAAAAAA";

    initscr();

    addstr(test);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

(compiled using -lncurses)

Where it shows simply `A` on the screen, instead of `AAAAAAA`.

If anyone has insight on why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated, as I haven't been able to find a similar problem elsewhere.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. The only thing you have told us is `char test[] = "AAAAAAA";` There is no "printing" that we can see.

Comment: addstr() should be the outputting function, from Ncurses. But sure, I'll add the complete code.